# Bootstrap 3 min-height div doesn't expand

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap 3 page with a centered box which contains content. 
If the content grows the box stays static and doesn't grows with my content but the bootstrap container grows.
I don't know why the "box" did'nt expand. I tried "position:relative" and "overflow:hidden" but it doesn't work.
I tried also "container-fluid" - no reaction.

My CSS-Stylesheet:

```
   html,
    body {
        height:100%;
        width:100%;
    }

    .container {
        height:100%;
        min-height:100%;
    }

    .row {
        height:100%;
        min-height:100%;
    }
.box {
    height:90%;
    min-height:90%;
    max-width:1100px;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.83);
    text-align:left;
    padding-left:5%;
    padding-right:5%;
    padding-top:1%;
    overflow:hidde;
    position: relative;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="box">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please provide a JSFiddle so we can see what you're achieving/ trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have hardcoded the height of you box, thats why it doesnt grow as more content comes in. You have to set the `height` to `auto`. And if you want that the box has a minimum height while not so much content is present just use an additional `min-height: 100vh;`

```
.box {
    height:auto;
    min-height: 100vh;
    /* etc.
}
```

See working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/19080/)

Comment: Thank you, it works.

That's embarrassing for myself. :D

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using bootstrap, try to make like this

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 box">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and then make the height like:

```
.box
{ 
  height: 100%;
}
```